# How to calculate the number of ways to arrange $x$ items in $y$ different containers, with each container have different size

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, recreational-mathematics

Example: 
There are $3$ containers, with capacity $4, 2,$ and $3$ items, respectively. How many way to arrange $6$ items on those containers?

Answer: 
container size $= 4, 2, 3$ 
number of items to be arranged $= 6$ 
possible arrangement with container size of: 
$4, 2, 3 \leftarrow$ container  size 
 
$1, 2, 3 \leftarrow$ 1st arrangement 
$2, 1, 3 \leftarrow$ 2nd arrangement
$2, 2, 2 \leftarrow$ 3rd arrangement
$3, 0, 3 \leftarrow$ 4th arrangement
$3, 1, 2 \leftarrow$ 5th arrangement
$3, 2, 1 \leftarrow$ 6th arrangement
$4, 0, 2 \leftarrow$ 7th arrangement
$4, 1, 1 \leftarrow$ 8th arrangement
$4, 2, 0 \leftarrow$ 9th arrangement

as such there are $9$ possible arrangements. So the answer is $9$.

How to calculate that, instead of doing it manually?

Comment: You could use a generating function, for example the coefficient of $x^6$ in the expansion of $(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)(1+x+x^2)(1+x+x^2+x^3)$  $= 1 + 3 x + 6 x^2 + 9 x^3 + 11 x^4 + 11 x^5 + 9 x^6 + 6 x^7 + 3 x^8 + x^9$

Comment: Another way is to note this is the number of ways of leaving $4+2+3 - 6=3$ spaces in the boxes, which is ${5 \choose 3} -1$ since the 2-box cannot have 3 spaces (though if it did then there would be 0 spaces left for the other boxes)

Comment: where does the 5 on $\binom{5}{3}$ come from?

Comment: $x$ is an arbitrary variable used to enable suitable power series addition and multiplication, but otherwise of no interest.  The interesting things are the exponents and coefficients.   For example, $(1+x+x^2)$ or more precisely $(1\times x^0 +1\times x^1 +1\times x^2)$ tells you there is one way each of putting 0, 1 or 2 items in the 2-box.

Comment: The ${5 \choose 3}$ or ${3+3-1 \choose 3}$ is a stars-and-bars way of counting the number of ways allocating 3 indistinguishable spaces to 3 boxes.

Comment: thanks Henry I understand now :)

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.